# Synaptics broken

Tags: stable-release-updates

I was trying to install vlc player and I installed it manually:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

The install messed up and gave me this error

```
E: The package libvlccore5 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.
```

Now every time I open synaptics package manager it gives me this error and closes. I can't install this package.

I checked the permissions and they are all OK.

Comment: What command did you run to install "manually"? Have you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Pleae [edit] your question to add new information. Adding a link in the comments is easy to miss. Have you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: try `sudo aptitude install vlc`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be `taskjuggler`.

Open a console and type in the following:

Code:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Search through the file for any reference to taskjuggler and CAREFULLY delete all of that entry.

Save the file

Code:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Your problem should now be solved, as Synaptic can no longer see this errant

Gratefully, this simple fix worked! (tip for newbies like me: use the search tool in gedit, as the data is lengthy)

I hope this helps someone. Enjoy!

Comment: i don't found any    taskjuggler sorry

Comment: any solution for my probleme???? ?